# How to convert a whole no stored as float in to string?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a column which is of float64 datatype:

Numbers = [1, 2.3, 3, 4.5, 5]

Now i will have to convert this column to object data type for a comparison

when i convert the data type of the column using df['Numbers'].astype(str), my column gets decimals for whole nos
ex: 1 becomes 1.0. i couldn't bring the expected output

the expected output is 1,2.3,3,4.5,5

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Use custom lambda function for test by [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[1, 2.3, 3, 4.5, 5]})

df['new'] = df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)) if x.is_integer() else str(x))
```

Another alternative is test if integer is same like float:

```
df['new'] = df['Numbers'].apply(lambda x: str(int(x)) if x == int(x) else str(x))
```

---

```
print (df)
   Numbers  new
0      1.0    1
1      2.3  2.3
2      3.0    3
3      4.5  4.5
4      5.0    5
```